# REST API to create Stellar account?

Tags: api, stellar

In the [REST API documentation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/operations-for-account.html), I didn't see an option to create an account. Obviously then, the [code snippet here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/create-account.html) to create an account has to be front-ended by some other API so that a request to create an account can be catered to. I am not sure why this is so. Is there a `HTTP POST` REST API to create an account?

Also, normally, to build a REST interface, one starts with identifying all 'resources' whose state changes over time and can be changed in a state-less operation. Then, for every such resource, the CRUD operations are implemented. For example, in Stellar, the resources could be account, anchor, trustlines, transactions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is no REST endpoint to create an account. An account is implicitly created after receiving at least 20 lumens.

To create an account:

1. Generate a private/public keypair. You can use the [Stellar Laboratory Account Creator](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#account-creator?network=test) for that.
2. Get at least 20 lumens, either from an exchange or through another account, sent to the public key you just created.

That's it.

Official guide : https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/create-account.html

Comment: Hello there Mr. Weller, so, is there a way to generate the private/public keypair without having to resort to using the SDKs?

Comment: @jlstr Yes, you will need to use a crypto library that implements ed25519. You can see how the Stellar SDKs do that for reference. For example, [Here's the Java keypair implementation](https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/org/stellar/sdk/KeyPair.java).

Answer (score 0):

Just as the documentation clearly mentions,

> To create a test account, send Friendbot the public key you created. It’ll create and fund a new account using that public key as the account ID.

- Create your own public key use ED25519 public-key signature system
- Perform a GET to the request friendlybot `https://friendbot.stellar.org/?addr=`

Comment: I think he wants to get a real account, not a test one, and he's asking how to create it without going through an exchange